# About django searchname

Tags: python, django

Please help me, I have this error:

> Exception Type:   UnboundLocalError Exception Value:   local variable
>   'query_string' referenced before assignment

this is my views.py:

```
def normalize_query(query_string,
                    findterms=re.compile(r'"([^"]+)"|(\S+)').findall,
                    normspace=re.compile(r'\s{2,}').sub):

    return [normspace(' ', (t[0] or t[1]).strip()) for t in findterms(query_string)] 

def get_query(query_string, search_fields):

    query = None # Query to search for every search term        
    terms = normalize_query(query_string)
    for term in terms:
        or_query = None # Query to search for a given term in each field
        for field_name in search_fields:
            q = Q(**{"%s__icontains" % field_name: term})
            if or_query is None:
                or_query = q
            else:
                or_query = or_query | q
        if query is None:
            query = or_query
        else:
            query = query & or_query
    return query

@login_required    
def search_name(request):
    form = ArticleForm(request.POST) 
    if ('q' in request.POST) and request.POST['q'].strip():
        query_string = request.POST['q']
        entry_query = get_query(query_string, ['user_name', 'company',])
        articles = User.objects.filter(entry_query).order_by('-pub_date')
    else:
        index = User.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')

    return render_to_response('index.html',
                          { 'query_string': query_string, 'index': index },
                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

index.html:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<label for="id_q"></label>
<input name="q" id="id_q" type="text">
<p><input type="submit" value="Search" class="button"></p></form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If `('q' in request.POST) and request.POST['q'].strip()` evaluates to `False`, `query_string` variable stays undefined.

One way to fix the problem is to initialize the variable before the `if` statement:

```
@login_required    
def search_name(request):
    form = ArticleForm(request.POST) 
    query_string = None
    if ('q' in request.POST) and request.POST['q'].strip():
    ...
```

Hope that helps.